# Using number formatting on a scientific number changes the value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a string which is `eval_id = -8880305704784521238` in google sheet.

When I used split formula `=SPLIT(A1,"=")` it gives me result in scientific number
`eval_id    -8.88031E+18`

But when I used number formatting it changes the value of the number.`-8880305704784520000` which is not equal to the actual number `-8880305704784521238`.

How can I fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: do you really want to do calculations with this number? If not, then just make it a text: `="-8880305704784521238"`

Comment: but how can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"-*\d*.?\d+")
```

[image: example]

or as an array formula (specify the range):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A15,"-*\d*.?\d+"))
```

[image: example]

Comment: no does not work for me. I just updated my result in my question.

Comment: @Mask in the screenshot, you are showing the **result** of the split formula, not the **actual input**. Can you show me the input?  Namely, column A.